# How to find the right statistical model / method for a given problem?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, random-forest

This is a very general question, but I couldn't find anything helpful via Google, or better, I didn't know how to formulate my question so that the right results turn up.

Is there a way or an algorithm I can follow or a set of questions I can answer to find the best model / method for a given problem? Like e.g.:

1. What do you want to do with the data / what is your desired result? -> comparing groups, forecasting, finding correlations,...
2. What kind of data do you have? -> time series data,...
3. How much data do you have?
4. ...

and so on.
(In my head the perfect thing would be like a diagram I can follow and which results in something like "Linear Regression!")

Right now I have a specific problem I need this for, but I struggle with this in general, so tips for both would be very much appreciated.

The problem I'm trying to solve right now is a forecasting problem. I am supposed to predict the amount of sales of a product for the coming years. The problem is, that I have only little data (which makes the standard ARIMA difficult). Also, I only have data from the last 13 years, which is additionally not even split up in months (so I have only the sales numbers for the whole year). Plus, I only really have one explanatory variable.

Any tips?

Feel free to ask for more information.
Also feel free to tell me if this is the wrong place to ask questions like this, I am new to all of this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site Nina. This is a great question but, unfortunately (imo) it's not answerable. Yes it's all these things and more. Almost infinitely more. In fact, it encapsulates all of statistics. My professional opinion is that it boils down to: is your model defensible? As much as the experimental design, and the hypothesis are defensible so must be the way you summarize the results.

Answer (score 0):

What AdamO says, basically no.

I know that *Handbook of Parametric and Nonparametric Statistical Procedures* by D. Sheskin has a bunch of tables which say things like "what kind of data do you have", "what are you aiming to determine" and then have a bunch of tests you could use. But there is no "right" answer.